# Nosetests not reading the config file

Tags: nose

.noserc

```
[nosetests]
with-xunit
```

Runnig the nosetest using the following command

```
nosetests -w ./test/unit_test
```

When I run the test using nosetests it does not create a nosetests.xml file.
But if I run the command below it does generate the nosetests.xml file.

```
nosetests -w ./test/unit_test --with-xunit
```

Not sure why it is not reading the .noserc file when I run nosetests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the configuration file to the home directory did the trick.

```
~/.noserc
```

Answer (score 7):

You can either have a `.noserc` file in your user/home directory, or you can have a file of the same format in your project directory under the name `setup.cfg`

Comment: the docs are ambiguous/incorrect about this: http://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage.html : " you may also put configuration options in a .noserc or nose.cfg file in your home directory. "